# covariance in react refs and typescript generics

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Typescript allows Covariance. The following code is valid, even though `createElement('p')` is strongly typed and returns an `HTMLParagraphElement`:

```
let p: HTMLElement = document.createElement('p');
```

At the same time, the following tsx code is not valid:

```
export default function RefProblem() {
  const myRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
  return <p ref={myRef}>text</p>;
}
```

It produces an error message:

```
Type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLParagraphElement>'.
```

This is a surprise to me, I always thought that the typechecks in Typescript would allow covariance in generic classes. So I went to the typescript playground and created this example. Everything behaves just as expected:

```
class A { aval: number = 0; };
class B extends A { bval: number = 0; };

let a: A = new A();
let b: B = new B();

a = b; // ok
b = a; // error

class G<T>{ gval?: T };

let ga: G<A> = new G();
let gb: G<B> = new G();

ga = gb; //ok
gb = ga; //error
```

Why does covariance not work for generic react refs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While testing the code I realized my mistake. Maybe this will be useful to someone else, so I'll still post the question.

I thought that the reference will wrap a `RefObject<HTMLParagraphElement>` in the supertype `RefObject<HTMLElement>`. This should be fine.

But before this can happen, the react ref that has been created needs to be assigned to the JSX attribute. And here it's the inverse. I'm trying to assign a `RefObject<HTMLElement>` to an attribute of type `RefObject<HTMLParagraphElement>`.

So the typecheck makes a completely valid complaint. This should fail.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the fact that React’s typings predate [TypeScript’s variance annotations](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48240).

`useRef` is typed to return `RefObject<T>`. If `RefObject<T>` were declared as `RefObject<in T>`, the check would succeed, whereas the inverse (assigning a `RefObject<HTMLParagraphElement>` to a `ref` on a `<span>`) wouldn’t.